# Should I use OpenVPN or IPsec

Tags: security

Which would you consider to be more secure between two servers that send and receive XML data?

OpenVPN or IPsec? I am currently using OpenVPN. I have been told that Open VPN put the client server at risk. this is a always connection.

Comment: but being told something does not make it true, you really need to investigate the claims.

Comment: What's a "client server" and "a always connection" in this context?

Comment: IPSec has mechanisms for making sure the source and destination IP of a packet stays intact (and a way around that with NAT-T) - i.e. if the path of traffic changes between two IPSec hosts they can know about it.  Since OpenVPN is SSL over standard TCP or UDP, it's routable, and hosts wouldn't know if traffic was being re-routed for whatever reason.  That's the only difference I can think of but I'm not terribly knowledgeable about IPSec.

Answer (score 2):

OpenVPN supports server AND client validation through certificates.

I've used it for years and have never heard any reasonable argument that it is not secure. It is as secure as its configuration.

That said, both OpenVPN and IPSEC has their respective advantages and problems. Since you've already got OpenVPN working I suggest you start by analyzing your required security level and match it with your current configuration - specifically start using certificates if you can.